# How to move the top links to the navigation bar Magento 2

Tags: magento2, navigation

I would like to put the top links (Login, Create Account, Log out, ...) to my navigation bar. Any idea how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What we need to do

To move a block you need to use the `<move>` XML instruction, the official docs for this can be found [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv)

### Finding the block name

To move a block you first need to find out the block name, in this case I searched for `header links` within `magento2/app` as I know these css classes are added via the XML. This gives me 2 results:

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

And

```
app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

If you search these 2 XML files for `header links` you will see where the blocks are called and the name passed to it. Which file you need depends on your fallback structure, if you're falling back to Luma view the first file, if you're falling back to the blank theme use the second file.

My theme is using the blank theme so I can see the block name is `top.links`, this is on line 50 of `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` (*If your theme is falling back to Luma I believe the block name is `header.links`*).

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

### Moving the block

Now we know the class name we can move the block, in my example I have moved the block to the footer. As I want this to happen on every page I have added the below code to

```
app/design/frontend/*MY_STORE_NAME*/*MY_THEME_NAME*/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml.

<move element="top`.links" destination="footer_links" />
```

It's important to add this to your own theme and not overwrite Magento's code.

### Result

My XML code now looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="top.links" destination="footer_links" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Which renders the links in the footer on the front end:

[image]

I hope this helps.

### Update 1 - Above the nav

To move the links above the nav this is the only line of code required.

```
<move element="top.links" destination="page.top" before="-" />
```

### Update 2 - In the nav

To add the links **inside** the nav I think your options are to hardcode them by adding `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml` to your theme and adding the links you require there.

Or if you need them to be dynamic then you'll beed to do some back-end work to give the `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` block class the ability to check and render account links depending on if the user is signed in. I'm not a back-end dev so I can't help much with this method, if you choose to go down this method the following files may help you out:

```
- vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
- vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
- vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml
- vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
```

### Update 3 - Add to the same section as the logo and search bar

To find the name of the section that contains the logo and search bar I searched Magento's XML files for the classes used on their parent container which are `header content`. This returns the following code in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`:

```
<container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
```

So we can see the container name is `header-wrapper` meaning we can use the below code to move our element there:

```
<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" />
```

You can position it where you want with before and after.

Comment: This works but how do you move the header links to the **navigation bar**? Or right above the navigation bar?

Comment: I have added 2 updates to my answer, one explains how to add them above the nav bar, and the other gives some assistance in how to add them inside the navigation.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how to move the same links to the area where the logo and search bar are located? I've tried to change the `destination` value in this line: `<move element="top.links" destination="page.top" before="-" />` but I haven't found the way to position the links in that area, just above the search bar and below the original position in Blank theme. In other words, they are inside the `<div class ="panel wrapper">`, and I want to take them out from there to the area above the search bar.

Comment: I've included that into my answer now (update 3) - the destination should be header-wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! I think this should be marked as the best answer @Omitri. Regarding the header links, in their original position the links dont have bullets, but when I moved them to `header-wrapper`, bullets appear in each link. And if I move them to `footer_links` bullets dont appear.

Comment: This will likely be LESS/CSS related, you will need to add list-style: none; to the UL or LI