# How do I move all the elements of the header to the navigation menu

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I need to move all the items in the header to the navigation menu and have the navigation menu before the header

[image]

Comment: please check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103503/how-to-move-the-top-links-to-the-navigation-bar-magento-2 I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code you default.xml file.

```
<move element="minicart" destination="header-wrapper" before="top.search"/>
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper"/>
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header.panel"/>
<move element="header.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="minicart"/>
```

After add this css you custom.css file

```
ul.header.links {
    float: right;
}
```

And remove the top navbar menu background color.

After run this `php bin/magento c:f`

**Output:-** 
[image]

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Hello @Andres Higuita it's help or not ???